# How can I get Intellij to show more frames of stack in the run console?

Tags: intellij-idea

At run time, the run console shows something like:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getHooksInterface(RobolectricTestRunner.java:455)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.robolectric.internal.ParallelUniverse.<init>(ParallelUniverse.java:32)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No shadows modules found containing a org.robolectric.ShadowsAdapter
    at org.robolectric.Robolectric.instantiateShadowsAdapter(Robolectric.java:91)
    at org.robolectric.Robolectric.<clinit>(Robolectric.java:14)
    ... 35 more
```

I would like see all of the frames, instead of "... 35 more"

This is with IntelliJ 2016.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File | Settings | Editor | General | Console